# CSS styling not showing up on Django app

Tags: html, css, django

I have my CSS in the following path: mysite/myapp/static/myapp/style.css. As of now, the CSS is simply:

```
body {
  background-color: #F2B8F0
}

h1 {
  color: #7BE0CB
}
```

I have my HTML set up like  this: mysite/myapp/templates/myapp/home.html, where the following code is up on top:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'myapp/style.css' %}" />
```

My settings.py is like:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

However, nothing happened, and the different text and background colors aren't showing up in my HTML. Does anyone happen to know why? Thanks!

Comment: Tell you can access `localhost.com:8000/static/myapp/style.css`

Comment: I am running this on AWS, but I can't access http://{{randoma amazon aws stuff}}.compute-1.amazonaws.com/static/myapp/style.css

Comment: Are you using  django-storages  for static file serve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your css link tag is in the incorrect spot within your HTML. It should be as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

{% load static %}

<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'myapp/style.css' %}" />
  </head>
  <!-- YOUR HTML HERE -->
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

let

```
 {% load static %}
```

be your first line in your HTML